# Can I take a break from prayer until I fix the mistakes?

Tags: halal-haram, salat

I literally cannot pray without making mistakes and having to repeat. No matter what I do! Is it permissible for me to take a break until I can fix this problem? And if so, do I have to make up for it? And does it do anything bad?

I know the proper way to pray and have been praying for 5 years but OCD has kicked in, and I cannot relax at all if I pray while making mistakes, even if this does not invalidate my salah. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Delaying salah is haram. If you make a mistake in salah that will invalidate it, then you have to break it and do it again but you cannot delay it. You have to pray salah at it's given time unless there is a valid reason, i.e Travelling

Answer (score 5):

This state of mind is referred to as *Kathirush shak* (کثیر الشک)/
one who doubts too much.
And in this state one can and should ignore their
doubt and assume that they have correctly performed that part
of the prayer which they have doubt in.

I have to say the details of deeming a person Kathirush shak
wasn't easy to understand ([p.418](http://www.sistani.org/files-new/book-pdf/persian-tozih-jame.pdf)) and not easy to explain.
But, if you doubt at least in every third prayer for
more than three times then you can deem yourself as 
Kathirush shak.

> A normal person who doubts at least once in every three prayers, should ignore his doubts.
>   [*Things which invalidate prayers » One who doubts too much*](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2242/)

As a plus, if it is convenient for you to attend congregrational
prayers and offering your prayers in it gives you peace from this
excessive doubting then you *must* attend the congregration.

> If a person is so obsessed with doubts and anxiety during prayers,
>   that it leads to its invalidity, and if he finds peace only in
>   congregational prayers, he must offer prayers in congregation.
>   [Congregational prayers » Introduction](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2252/)

> Can I take a break from prayer until I fix the mistakes?

It is not at all permissible to halt or take a break from
saying prayers. It's forbidden to do so, and if done
one has to make up for them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you asked such a question.
This happens with most and very less worry about it.

First of all, I would not suggest to take a break from Salah (prayer) and if you deliberately mis-salah then you will have to face the consequences in the here after.

So when you know the proper way of prayer and because of OCD prayer is going wrong, then all you have to do is pray for guidance from Allah. The best way to make things right. And do not skip your prayer because of this reason, keep praying, seek for Allah's guidance.

Al'hamdulillahi Rabbil'Aalameen !

Assalamu'alaikum Warahamatullahi Wabarakatuh.

Answer (score 0):

It can best be done while continuing with one's obligations---mandatory prayers. This is probably the best example of a difference between Divine wisdom and man's wisdom. Even the man in some respects says  "practice Makes man Perfect" then why to abandon a good deed just to deprive oneself of perfection?